# JPA lower() function on parameter

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, named-parameters

I have updated project from spring 3.2 to 4.1 and hibernate 4.2 to 4.3.7 and got interesting problem.
I have query:

```
function parameter: String email;
getQuery(getSelect() + "where lower(o.email) = lower(:email)").setParameter("email", email);
```

now, on getting result I got

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does
>   not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument
>   types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

but if I call

```
getQuery(getSelect() + "where lower(o.email) = lower('test')")
```

or

```
getQuery(getSelect() + "where lower(o.email) = lower(:email)").setParameter("email", "test")
```

it works fine.

Comment: Does it work when you explicitly specify parameter type, eg. `setParameter("email", email, StringType.INSTANCE)` ?

Comment: Weird issue. It seems that Hibernate is for some reason sending the type-parameter as `bytea` (or rather, probably `java.sql.Types.BLOB`), instead of leaving it for the server to infer or setting it to `text` (`java.sql.Types.STRING`).

Comment: so why not look in the log at what is the SQL that it is trying to use? I've used that type of syntax in the JPA implementation I use (DataNucleus) and had no problems

Answer (score 0):

setParameter("email", email, StringType.INSTANCE) - solved my issue, thanks for help!