# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does not exist

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, lowercase, named-parameters

I'm in a migration process from javax to jakarta.
Our project is build with Spring Boot (thus upgrade from 2.7 to 3.2) and Hibernate (5.6 to 6.3) and we use a PostgreSQL database (V14). One pitfall was the migration of a custom PostgreSQL dialect, but i suppose i solved satisfactory (-> implementation of a full text search condition)

The main issue arises when we perform a query:

> ```
>       SELECT o FROM Order o
>        WHERE (o.createdAt between :from and :to)
>        AND (:query is null OR function('pgTextSearch', :query, o) = true)
>        AND (:createdBy is null OR LOWER(o.createdBy) = LOWER(:createdBy))
> ```

It says:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function lower(bytea) does not exist
> Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

So far as i know, this comes from an invocation of the lower() function with 'null' as parameter. :createdBy is declared as string (resp. varchar). In my scenarion :createdBy is null, but this should be intercepted by the first OR condition. What am i missing?

Additionally, i executed the query with replaced parameters through PostgreSQL-CLI without issues.

P.S. The query was modified for migration, but only within the custom function part.
P.P.S. I read the migration guides for spring boot and hibernate (SQM yikes!), but could not find any overlap to my use case.
P.P.P.S. I'm not setting the parameter by hand (e.g. .[setParameter("createdBy", xyz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663235/jpa-lower-function-on-parameter)), the repository is a JpaRepository, thus parameter replacement is done by Spring Data

Comment: does `LOWER(cast(:createdBy as TEXT))` work?

Comment: I'm totally confused. I know i've tried to cast the value, but somehow the results did not fit my expectations...  
Though i don't understand, why Hibernate or PostgreSQL evaluate the second term even if it conditionally doesn't matter.  
@AndreyB.Panfilov Please post your answer and i'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short story**

You are hitting, more than 10 years old bug:

- [Add support for setObject(, null)](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/3)
- [Simple JPQL with guarded null Parameter fails with Postgresql](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/JPA-31)

**Long story**

I. Hibernate, since v6, does have an API which allows to overcome such issues, for example:

```
    /**
     * Bind the given argument to a named query parameter using the given
     * Class reference to attempt to determine the {@link BindableType}
     * to use.  If unable to determine an appropriate {@link BindableType},
     * {@link #setParameter(String, Object)} is used.
     *
     * @see #setParameter(String, Object, BindableType)
     */
    <P> Query<R> setParameter(String parameter, P argument, Class<P> type);
```

unfortunately, you are using `spring-data-jpa`, and Spring team have not yet adopted new features of Hibernate v6 - here I would suggest to file a corresponding bug/cr.

II. It seems the main problem for particular query is following:

`:createdBy` parameter occurs two times in `:createdBy is null OR LOWER(o.createdBy) = LOWER(:createdBy)` clause, and there is definitely no option to infer correct sql type from `:createdBy is null` expression, however, technically, it should be possible to infer `varchar` sql type from `LOWER(o.createdBy) = LOWER(:createdBy)` expression, the problem is Hibernate is trying to infer sql type of query parameter only once, so you are getting weird `bytea` instead of `varchar` (here I have no idea why do not set default to something more common instead of `bytea`).

Could you try to flip `:createdBy is null` and `LOWER(o.createdBy) = LOWER(:createdBy)` expressions? I suspect it may fix the issue.

III. idiomatic way to write such "universal" queries is to use `SpEL` or JPA specifications, please check [Hibernate randomly throws error: Cannot coerce value `[]` [java.util.ArrayList] as Long](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572804/3426309)

Comment: Flipping the operands might help hibernate to determine the type, but a follow-up issue might arise if the query is sent to the database driver and lower-function is called with null-parameter before the null-safe-check is processed. I'll give it a try and report asap.

Comment: Flipping the operand did the trick, too. The query looks less complex with it, though it's not obvious why it was flipped (javadoc to the rescue). Nevertheless thank you so much @AndreyB.Panfilov