# Spring boot Postgres not return null when empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, null

I am using spring boot and spring data JPA with a Postgres database. There is a weird behaviour that happens when query something and the result is nothing.
In a lot of databases and projects when I make a query and the result was empty the returned object to java was null.
For example:

[image]

```
@Query(value = "select * from notification where WEBCODE = :webCode OR USERNAME = :username", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<NotificationSQL> getNotificationsAsPage(@Param( "webCode" ) String webCode,@Param( "username" ) String username, Pageable pageable);
```

In this case I was suppose to get a null page. but in this case I am receiving an exception

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
...

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bytea
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 42
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2552)
```

I do not understand why it does not just return a null object. It happens the same with the rest of the queries when empty rows and different objects as List classes. In a lot of projects this has not happen to me, the returned object when the query was right and empty rows was a null.

If the parameters are not null it works perfect, but the point is that these parameters sometimes are null and , as it can be seen in the image, the query works nice but with a result of empty rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: changed Thanks. I have change the query to code

Comment: When you do it by hand, typing `WEBCODE = null` you use a proper `null`. When Hibernate passes its idea of `null` into the query, it ends up inserting a `bytea` representation of it instead. Here's a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546344/error-operator-does-not-exist-character-varying-bytea) with a couple solutions.

Comment: @Zegarek it just happens in postgres?? because usisng another databases does not